USB HID device works on CentOS, FreeBSD, but not Mint
I have a Delcom USB button assembly that is intended for arcade applications as an HID input device.
It is recognized and operates correctly on FreeBSD 14 and CentOS 7, but not on Mint 21.
On both CentOS and Mint the device triggers entries in dmesg:
CentOS (3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64):
[  730.949881] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  731.038185] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0fc5, idProduct=b080
[  731.038192] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  731.038196] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB FS IO
[  731.038200] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Delcom Products Inc.
[  731.045382] input: Delcom Products Inc. USB FS IO as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input19
[  731.096612] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Delcom Products Inc. USB FS IO] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0

Mint (5.15.0-91-generic):
[    2.289804] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.440808] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0fc5, idProduct=b080, bcdDevice= 0.08
[    2.440833] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.440845] usb 1-5: Product: USB FS IO
[    2.440855] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Delcom Products Inc.
...
[    3.248504] input: Delcom Products Inc. USB FS IO Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:0FC5:B080.0002/input/input5
[    3.306486] input: Delcom Products Inc. USB FS IO Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:0FC5:B080.0002/input/input6
[    3.307123] input: Delcom Products Inc. USB FS IO as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:0FC5:B080.0002/input/input7
[    3.307767] hid-generic 0003:0FC5:B080.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Delcom Products Inc. USB FS IO] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
...
[  524.320773] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  532.181496] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  532.332805] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0fc5, idProduct=b080, bcdDevice= 0.08
[  532.332834] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  532.332848] usb 1-5: Product: USB FS IO
[  532.332859] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Delcom Products Inc.

lsusb on Mint shows it:
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0fc5:b080 Delcom Engineering USB FS IO

What do I need to tell Mint to get it to recognize this as an input device?

For some unholy reason they allow unusual HID drivers to have their own kernel modules.  So maybe check the kernel versions with uname -r and post them?
